# Getting Error while opening hosted KaiOS app

Tags: firefox-os, kaios

I have a `manifest.webapp` hosted at my application root (https://localhost:5001/manifest.webapp), when I open it in KaiOS simulator, I get the following error:

> Unable to access the app starting document `https://localhost:5001/`,
>   got HTTP code 405

Curl of its response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 02 Oct 2019 21:18:41 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-web-app-manifest+json
Content-Length: 6097
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Last-Modified: Tue, 01 Oct 2019 07:35:10 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "1d5782ac10b5cd1"
Set-Cookie: ClientId=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; samesite=lax
Set-Cookie: ClientId=922A46E87C9646C18555E7E7DE84840F; expires=Mon, 02 Oct 2119 21:18:42 GMT; path=/; samesite=lax
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
x-frame-options: allow-from https://example.com/
x-web-server-version: 1.0.0.0
x-besku: UNKNOWN

{
  "name": "abc",
  "short_name": "abc",
  "icons": [..],
 "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/abc/?start_url=sss",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "theme_color": "#0078d7"

...
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox os/kaios makes a HEAD call, before GET, so that should be implemented on your server, else this error will come.